# How to force a linked document to be downloadable or viewable

Tags: html

I want to offer both `View` and `Download` options for downloadable documents on a webpage.  ie. I want to force the browser to either use a plugin viewer or save directly to the computer.  These documents will most likely be PDF or word and possibly others.  Is there a way I can do that directly in the html/css/javascript?  I do not have access to the server itself.  Preferably all browsers will support this.

**EDIT:**  Both answers are good ones so I won't chose one in particular.  Instead I'll vote both of them up.

Comment: Wow, both answers are good ones.....

Comment: Do you happen to be using Moodle? Or is it another type of CMS.

Comment: I don't think it's Moodle.  Never used Moodle before.

Answer (score 1):

To get the link to force download you could use the following HTML5 option.

```
<a href='file.pdf' download=''>Link [Download]</a>
```

To view in the browser you could also have the following link:

```
<a href='file.pdf'>Link [View]</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Though TheShinyTuxedo's answer will work, it wont work with older browsers which don't support HTML 5.

**To support all browsers, make your link like this:**

`<a href="file.pdf" target="_blank">Download</a>`

By setting `target="_blank"`, your browser will open the file in a new tab and immediatly close it and download the file

---

Ok in response to your comment, this is gonna be tricky which will require a bit of additional work...
Assuming you are using php, the solution is to create a download script which sends headers to the browser explicitly telling it to download the file.

---

**So First create a `download.php` file and put the following script in:**

```
<?php
   $filename = $_GET["file"]
   header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);
   header("Content-type: application/pdf");
   readfile($filename);
?>
```

**Then your download link would look like this:**

```
<a href="download.php?file=myfile.pdf" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

This should work because the headers sent to the browser explicitly tells the browser, that the following content is ment to be donwloaded and not just displayed.

**P.S:** If you are using just html, then I don't think there is a solution...

Comment: For some reason Chrome doesn't perform a download for me.  It just shows the document in the new tab???

Comment: @PaulMatthews hmm, this is going to be a bit tricky, have a look at my updated answer

Comment: Thanks for the extra work but I only have access to the html.  Unfortunately the changes I can make are very limited due to working with a content management system.

Comment: @PaulMatthews Well in that case you'll have to do what `TheShinyTuxedo` says but you wont get backward compatibility on browsers which don't support html 5 unfortunatly